# VB.Net Photo Booth Project

Tags: vb.net, webcam, mouseclick-event

So my older sister's high school graduation is coming up soon. She really enjoy's looking at pictures of her friend so I had this idea to make a photo booth style program. At this point, I have the webcam to display on a picturebox, however the click and mouseclick subroutines are not working. Does anyone know why this could be?

```
    Private Sub picCapture_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picCapture.MouseClick
        MsgBox("hi")
End Sub

    Dim iHeight As Integer = picCapture.Height
        Dim iWidth As Integer = picCapture.Width

        hHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA(DeviceID.ToString, WS_VISIBLE Or WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 1280, _
            1024, picCapture.Handle.ToInt32, 0)

        If SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, DeviceID, 0) Then

            SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, True, 0)

            SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 66, 0)

            'Start previewing the image from the camera

            SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, True, 0)

            SetWindowPos(hHwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, picCapture.Width, picCapture.Height, _
                    SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOZORDER)

        Else
            ' Error connecting to device close window
            DestroyWindow(hHwnd)
        End If
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: What API is this? ASP.NET? Winforms? Windows Store? Mono?

Comment: CapCreateCaptureWindow in vb.net